# ActiveMQ 5.15.11 giving issues in JBoss 7.3

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic

```
11:36:32,554 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "activemq-rar.rar")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.activemq-rar.activemq-rar.env.1"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.activemq-rar.activemq-rar.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.activemq-rar.activemq-rar.env.1]"]
}
11:36:33,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "activemq-rar.rar" (runtime-name : "activemq-rar.rar")
11:36:33,115 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.activemq-rar.activemq-rar.env.1 (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.activemq-rar.activemq-rar.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory] 
WFLYCTL0448: 1 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
11:36:33,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
11:36:33,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9992/management
11:36:33,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9992
11:36:33,421 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.3.0.GA (WildFly Core 10.1.2.Final-redhat-00001) started (with errors) in 34488ms - Started 960 of 1384 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 715 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```